# Mercurial hooks: how to find the current directory on commit

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am trying to create a hook to Mercurial SCM (hg) using C# .NET, to launch a custom C# application on commit or pre-commit.

As a proof-of-concept prototype, I added a location of my custom .exe to the Mercurial.ini file's [hooks] section for pre-commit, and another .exe for commit.
Those .exe apps open on pre-commit and commit, as expected.

However, those executables are only stubs so far.
To make them do what I need, they have to "know" the current directory where the commit is about to occur (or has occurred).
Mercurial.ini is located in my user profile directory on Windows.
For example, when I do a commit from an Hg repository located in C:\MyProjects\TestProject, the executables need to know that the work is being done in C:\MyProjects\TestProject.

How can I find out programmatically at runtime from a "hooked" executable where the Mercurial command is being executed on the local machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [hook chapter in the book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#x_228):

> An executable hook is always run with its current directory set to a
>   repository's root directory.

So your executable can just check its current working directory to know the root directory of the repo on which it's being called.

Comment: This is it! Thank you very much! GetCurrentDirectory method of the System.IO.Directory class does the trick. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it worked out.  For the record compiled hooks sound like crazy-sauce.  Are you sure you don't want want to use a nice scripting language?  C# is a fine language for large systems, but unless you're building something monolithic a compile/link cycle seems like overkill.

Comment: Ry4an: Once again, thank you very much for your help. Answering your question: I use C# for the hooks executables because while I am very proficient in C#, I do not know the first thing about Python or any other scripting language, and the executables will need to do a lot of complex stuff eventually... So, given the time constraints, I'd rather use what I know very well. However, while I was writing this, I gave it a second thought... and I think you are absolutely right. And I am making plans to learn at least one scripting language. Thank you very much for that suggestion, too!