# How to get the working directory of the command from an hg hook?

Tags: mercurial

I'm working on a commit hook for Mercurial and running into problems with relative paths.

Say my hook wants to look at the contents of the files being committed and warn if any contain the phrase "xyzzy". However, the user has decided to call commit from a subfolder and pass in the name of the file as a pattern...

```
C:\clone\subdir> hg commit file.txt -m 'test'
```

My hook is called with C:\clone as the working directory, but HG_PATS contains simply file.txt with no subdir\ prefix. How can I get the working directory of the hg command itself? I can't find a way to do this in docs.

The only way I can figure out how to get it is look up the process tree to find the first hg.exe and get its working directory. But that's not exactly portable to other OS's. (And I know I could write an extension, but would really like to avoid that.)

Comment: This was previously answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903986/mercurial-hooks-how-to-find-the-current-directory-on-commit
(the current dir always is the repository root within a hook)

Comment: How is this hook written, batch file, powershell, python?

Comment: It's perl, but what matters is that it's hooking through [hooks], which starts the process with working dir as repo root and doesn't communicate what the working dir was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers and comments, but after some more research I determined there's no clean way to do what I want from an external hook. I did implement the CWD hack I mentioned in my question. Not a ton of code, but quite nasty, and on Windows it requires undocumented access to external process CWD via [tlist.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It works, but..yuck.

The right way to do this appears to be to write an [in-process hook](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) (example library at [hghooklib](https://code.google.com/p/hghooklib/)). Usual versioning caveats apply as with writing any extension, though I think for our hooks the interface to hg is simple enough that we'll be ok.

(In my question I mentioned I didn't want to write an extension, but I was thinking of a full extension like hgeol. A hook-only extension with a single function entry point feels more constrained and simple, which is what I want at this point.)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `pretxncommit` hook then you are given `$HG_NODE` which is the commit id, but the commit hasn't been finalized at that point so you can still return 1 to cancel it.

Then you could use

```
hg log -r $HG_NODE --template '{files}'
```

to get the list of files in the commit, and it gives you the full path relative to the repo root.

It's not exactly what you were after but it might get you close enough to let you do the content examination you want.

Comment: The scenario is simplified a little in the question - the hook also lets users opt into auto-fixup (such as tabs<->spaces). I assume pre-commit is required for this because the hash would change.

Comment: Ah I see, you want to do the manipulation automatically and then carry on with the commit. The only other option I can think of would be to just do it on the pre-commit hook and just manipulate all the changed files in the working directory since you can't get the specific files being committed.

Comment: Yeah that's what a coworker suggested too, and until I can move my CWD hack out of experimental status, this is what we have to do. The problem is that this behavior may be very surprising to people ("why is it messing with a file I am not committing?") so I'm temporarily putting out a warning to remind users when specifying patterns that the hook will still apply to all modified files.